# After adding a route programmatically, when any route is accessed, angular throws an error when back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, built.io

My problem is that after adding the below code, which adds dynamic routes to my web app, my back key throws an error that i cannot diagnose.

This is a simple provider method i came across a while back that adds this functionality:

```
myApp.provider('$dashboardState', function($stateProvider){
    this.$get = function($state){
        return {
            addState: function(title) {
                $stateProvider.state(title, {
                    url: '/' + title,
                    templateUrl: "templates/" + title + '.html'
                });
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I can then add a route to my ui-router in any of my controllers like so:

```
//variable $urlName is fetched previously and is just a string

$url_name = $urlName;
$dashboardState.addState($url_name);
```

When i do this, however, and i redirect to the route i have made dynamically by clicking:

```
<a href="#/" + $urlName + "\">
```

in my html, it works flawless except when i click the back key in my browser, the console throws this error:

```
[Error] Potentially unhandled rejection [1] 
registerState@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/angular-ui-router.js:2361:53
state@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/angular-ui-router.js:2871:18
addState@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/app.js:22:37
http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/app.js:163:34
j@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/built.min.js:13:3777
O@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/built.min.js:13:3464
when@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/built.min.js:13:6577
run@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/built.min.js:13:5616
n@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/built.min.js:11:25298
_drain@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/built.min.js:11:25476
drain@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/built.min.js:11:25250
r@http://epicbiz.shotsevolved.com/js/built.min.js:6:13467
    (anonymous function) (built.min.js:13:707)
    r (built.min.js:13:328)
    c (built.min.js:13:592)
```

I'm only very new to angular but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking the source for angular-ui-router on line number 2361(that is where your error report said):

```
if (states.hasOwnProperty(name)) throw new Error("State '" + name + "' is already defined");
```

which means that u cannot register state with the same name twice.

However, when u back to the previous state, there could be chance that ur addState($url_name) is executed again. And this will cause the duplicate state name error.

Btw, i don't think it is a good idea to set states dynamically. If u insist on doing so, maybe check whether the state name is already there before adding it.

Comment: Thank you, i should have just checked it. Noob mistake, usually it throws me a generic, of course the on time i didn't, it's useful. Thanks!